# Cannot remove hash map from array list

Tags: java

```
public class PurchaseOrderWrapper extends ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> {

        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            HashMap<String, String> ob = (HashMap<String, String>) o;
            for (HashMap<String, String> map : this) {
                Log.i("kasun",ob.get("part_no")+" "+ map.get("part_no")+" = "+Boolean.toString(ob.get("part_no").equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("part_no"))));
                 if(ob.get("part_no").equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("part_no"))){
                     return true;
                 }
            }
        return false;
    }
}

if (wrapper.contains(removitems)){      
    wrapper.remove(removitems);     
}
```

Wrapper is a  instance of a PurchaseOrderWrapper class.it contains Hash Map with with 5 attributes including part no.remove items also contains  4 items inclding part no as i mention on the above example.So i need to remove the hashmap from Wrapper instance which has same part no in remove items hash map.But it does not work

Comment: What is `removitems` defined as?

Comment: removeitems is HashMap it contains 4 values

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove all items of `removitems` if your wrapper contains only one element of it? Because your method `contains` returns `true` even if only one element of `removitems` is equal element in `wrapper`.

Comment: Did you create `removitems` separately or did you retrieve it from the `ArrayList`? I don't believe `HashMap` overrides `equals()`, so could possibly be the source of your problem.

Comment: In my removeitems hash map contains  part_no  with another 3 attribute
.My wrapper arraylist contains hash maps.In each hasmap contains part_no.so i need to remove the hashmap from the wrapper Array list when it found hash map that has same part_no that reside in removeitems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're extending ArrayList (which you should never do), and breaking its contract.

You override `contains()` by saying that your list contains a given object if this object is a HashMap and happens to contain the same value for the "part_no" key as another map in the list. But you don't override remove(). And remove() keeps using the ArrayList's method, which removes the element in the list that is **equal** to the object passed as argument.

Don't, ever, extend the collection classes. Instead, wrap them inside your own class.

To implement the remove method, you'll probably have to iterate over the list, find the map in the list which has the same value for the "part_no" key as the map passed as argument, and remove that map from the list.

I have the suspicion that you're using Maps where you should define your own class ad well, but that doesn't change much.

Here's the skeleton of the class that you should have. You should figure out the implementation by yourself based on the above indications:

```
public class PurchaseOrderWrapper {
    private List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean containsElementWithSamePartNoAs(Map<String, String> map) {
        // iterate over the list and find if an element has the same part_no
        // as the map passed as argument
    }

    public void removeElementWithSamePartNoAs(Map<String, String> map) {
        // iterate over the list and find the element which has the same part_no
        // as the map passed as argument. Once found, remove this element from the list
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer can u explain little bot more or provide some example.I m new to java

Comment: i need to remove the entire hash map that contains the partno from the list

Comment: Yes, and that's what the skeleton and instructions above suggest you to do: iterate over the list of maps, find the map which has the same part_no as the map passed as argument, and remove this found map from the list. You understand that every element of a list of maps is a map, right?